# A Series-parallel circuit combination with current as input source

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, parallel, series

[image]

I am asked to find:
1.) the voltage drop |V|
2.) Current i1
3.) Current i2

So far I only managed to find the total resistance and total voltage which is 6 ohms and 72 volts respectively. I am really confused on where to start or what to find first. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Since you've already calculated the voltage drop across the total equivalent resistance, it doesn't matter anymore whether the source is a current source or a voltage source (because nothing in the circuit is changing) - don't let that confuse you. Just work back to where you need to go using voltage-divider & current-divider rules - expand the circuit back out in the reverse order you worked to collapse it into a single equivalent resistance..

Comment: As @brhans has said, work backwards from the simplified circuit using current division adding back one resistor at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage across the 4-ohm resistor, |V|, is the voltage across the left-side 12-ohm resistance (\$V_a\$) minus the voltage across the 6-ohm resistance, (\$V_b\$). Since you know the voltage across the 8-ohm resistance (72 V), you can determine \$V_a\$ by calculating the equivalent resistance loading the left-side 12-ohm resistance: \$R_{eq}=12||(4+6||12||4)\$. For the symbolic expression, do not develop the terms and keep the || as it is easier to read. Once you have that \$R_{eq}\$ value, you see a resistive divider with the 20-ohm resistance and \$R_{eq}\$. From the 72-V level you have calculated, apply that resistive divider and obtain \$V_a\$. Now that you have \$V_a\$, apply another resistive divider considering the 4-ohm resistance and the parallel combination of 6, 12 and 4 to obtain \$V_b\$. Calculate \$V_a-V_b\$ and you have what you want. With \$V_b\$, you have \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$.

As a side note, below is a resistive divider involving \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ in the left side.
[image]

The voltage at node a is equal to \$V_a=V_1\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_1}\$. If you now load \$R_2\$ with \$R_3\$ as shown in the right side, you have an equivalent resistance equal to \$R_{eq}=R_2||R_3\$ and the new division ratio becomes \$V_a=V_1\frac{R_{eq}}{R_{eq}+R_1}\$.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the current entering into the first node (node A)
that is 12 A as given, then you have to find the current through node B

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJbOE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For which,simplify the resistors to end up with only two resistors after node A,
for which you can refer to this link
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_5.html

you might end up with something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f52qFO.png)</sup>

now use the current division rule to find the current flowing through the resistor R2

current at R2 = I * (R1/R1+R2)

now you have found the current through node B, repeat the same neglecting the resistance before node B, to find current through node C, continue till you find all currents